# Pass ViewModel + Parameter to action using ajax call

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, actionmethod

How do I pass a view model and another parameter to my action method using jquery ajax?

with what I'm doing now, the action method is not being called. I think the cause is probably because the parameters are not being passed correctly in the data object of the jquery ajax call:

jQuery ajax:

```
$('#form-login').submit(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Account/LogOn/",
                    data: $('#form-login').serialize(),
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.userAuthenticated) {
                            window.location.href = data.url;
                        } else {
                            formBlock.clearMessages();
                            displayError($('#errorcred').val());
                        }
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        formBlock.clearMessages();
                        displayError($('#errorserver').val());
                    }
                });
        });
```

Action method (which accepts the view model and another parameter):

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        // Validate the email and password
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (MembershipService.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                FormsService.SignIn(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
                {
                    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                    {
                        return Json(new { userAuthenticated = true, url = returnUrl, isRedirect = true });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return Redirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                    {
                        return Json(new { userAuthenticated = true, url = Url.Action("Index", "Home"), isRedirect = true });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
        else
        {
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return Json(new { userAuthenticated = false, url = Url.Action("LogOn", "Account") });
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", adm.ErrorUserNamePassword);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the following from the $.ajax call:

```
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
```

You have specified `application/json` encoding but the `$('#form-login').serialize()` function is sending `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content.

As far as sending the returnUrl parameter is concerned, you could simply read it from the form `action` where it should be present (if you used the `Html.BeginForm()` helper):

```
$.ajax({
    url: this.action,
    ...
});
```

Also you probably want to rename the `event` variable with something else as this is a reserved word in javascript:

```
$('#form-login').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    ...
});
```

Comment: But how do the parameters get mapped correctly with $('#form-login').serialize() since I have two parameters for the action method ?

Comment: The `$('#form-login').serialize()` will only take the parameters that are present as `input` fields in the form. I noticed that you have a `returnUrl` parameter. This parameter is normally present in the query string when the Forms Authentication module redirected to the Login page. And if you used the `@Html.BeginForm()` helper in it, it will be part of the `action` attribute of the form. So when you use `url: this.action` instead of hardcoding it as you did (`url: "/Account/LogOn/"`) it will get passed to the action.

Comment: If you wanted to pass manually an additional parameter, the easiest would be to include a hidden field in your form and then set the value of this hidden field in your javascript code before calling the $.ajax method. Then the .serialize function will take it into account.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have found to do this is to just include the second parameter in your viewmodel and continue to serialize your form the way you are doing now.